# Install Python 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python

I have to use Ubuntu 12.04 for some reason. In the other hand, i have to use Python 2.7.8 but the newest python version for 12.04 is 2.7.3. Is there any ppa repository i can use to upgrade my python or other simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Download latest version tarball form python website https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/  and install it using http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: @sudheer, that's generally a bad idea. Mixing managed and unmanaged installs is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ppa for Python 2.7.10 which is relatively new. Please, read description here:

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7

1. Add PPA repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
   ```
2. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Then Install it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python2.7
   ```

Answer (score -3):

All versions of Python are available on Python web site. For the version 2.7.8, the download page is: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8

If you don't know how to install Python from the repository, you can use EasyInstall. [This page](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) explains how to install it and use it - it's very simple to use.

Comment: I dont' see how easy install helps to install **python** itself. But maybe I'm missing something. Could you explain?

Comment: Here are the details: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall

Comment: This won't work. EasyInstall is meant to install **python-modules**. It won't help you compile, link and install python itself.